# Limit sides of gameScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am developing a small `iOS` game in `swift`. I have got an image randomly appearing on the screen when you tap it. At the bottom I have an iAd banner. When generating random place,`arc4random` sometimes generates a place where the image is half off-screen or on the `iAd`. I would like to prevent it from doing that. How could I do that?
Any help is appreciated, really! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, where your sprite is half off the screen, you need to just take the width of the sprite and offset the `arc4random` by half.  Some pseudocode like this (it may work in Swift):

```
let width = self.sprite.size.width
// Set the position from the random
let x = (arc4random() % (self.viewWidth - width)) + (width / 2)
self.sprite.position = CGPointMake(x, <whatever y value>)
```

For the second part of your question, you do something similar, but with the height of the sprite and the y position.